# H2 support for adding NOT NULL constraint table column using Oracle syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, h2

I'm using H2 in Oracle mode. I added a column `bar` in table `foo` and filled it with values. Now I want to go back and give the column a `NOT NULL` constraint.

Looking at some [old Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj81859.html#rrefsqlj81859__rrefsqlj37860)  for `ALTER TABLE`, I first tried this:

```
ALTER TABLE foo ALTER COLUMN bar NOT NULL;
```

H2 tells me, `Unknown data type: "NOT" …`.

So I look at some [more recent Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm#SQLRF01001) for the `ALTER TABLE` syntax, and tried this:

```
ALTER TABLE foo MODIFY (bar VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL);
```

(Note that I don't need to change the type, but the production diagrams seems to indicate that it's needed.

H2 tells me, `Syntax error in SQL statement "ALTER TABLE FOO MODIFY ([*]BAR VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL) " …`

What am I doing wrong here? Is this a bug in H2's Oracle mode, or (more likely) am I missing something crucial with the syntax? (I haven't actually tried it on Oracle, but I figured something so basic would be supported in H2 in Oracle mode.)

*People, please read the question!* I am wanting the *Oracle* syntax. Yes, I am testing it against H2, because *I want to know whether H2 supports the Oracle syntax*! If you just tell me the H2 syntax, then how will I know if H2 supports the Oracle syntax??

Comment: If you are using H2 then you should read the [H2 manual](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html) not the Oracle manual. The "oracle mode" only simulates some very basic Oracle syntax parts. It does not make H2 behave like Oracle

Comment: We want it to behave like Oracle. If it doesn't be have like Oracle in Oracle mode, we want to file tickets and/or contribute resources to fixing H2 so that it does behave like Oracle in Oracle mode. So the question is: which (if either) of the SQL commands I provided above are valid Oracle syntax? Do they not work because I screwed up the SQL, or because H2 doesn't support this syntax? (Yes, I will read the H2 manual, but I want to first clarify if I have correct Oracle syntax.)

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Why don't you use Oracle then?

Comment: Ever tried to use Oracle as an in-memory database that spins up in microseconds and does Flyway migrations and runs Java unit tests and shuts back down, all within a second or two, in a Maven build? Look, this is not missing database functionality --- we're talking about a command syntax. H2 works great. It should be simple to allow it to recognize a different syntax in Oracle mode.

Comment: Testing against H2 when your production installation runs against Oracle makes no sense. They are way too many (even subtle) difference between Oracle and H2 that render those tests useless. The most obvious example: `insert into foo (bar) values ('')` would work in H2 but not in Oracle if the column is defined as `NOT NULL`. Just keep a dedicated Oracle instance up and running for your integration tests.

Comment: How can you even attempt to make such a blanket statement without knowing anything about my application? "Makes no sense" is a very extreme position to take without any knowledge of the specifics. Tables, `NOT NULL` constraints, inner joins --- this is all fundamental functionality (like for decades) with no "subtle" differences in the basic queries we're doing. We're not building rockets. We're looking up stuff in a few tables. We want to have some unit tests that test basic storing and querying functionality. We're not testing crazy subtleties.

Comment: …but the thing about Oracle considering the empty string to be `NULL` is a very useful thing to know. Thanks!

Comment: so that insert example is a "crazy subtlety"? Or the result of concatenating a null value to a string? Or the behaviour of unique indexes with null values? Or a simple `select * from foo as x`? Or a simple `SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE (a,b) IN (SELECT c,d FROM bar);`? Believe me: the differences are way bigger then you seem to expect.

Comment: Well I don't want to get into a deep argument about Oracle differences; obviously you have more extensive experience in that area. But could we get away from the side issue of "that makes no sense" to the actual question about which is the correct Oracle syntax? If you could indicate the correct Oracle syntax for this simple task, I would appreciate it. And improving H2 to _support_ that syntax wouldn't hurt anything, would it? I mean, wouldn't that make the world a better place, even if there still exist "crazy subtleties"? :)

Comment: The correct syntax in Oracle is `ALTER TABLE FOO MODIFY BAR NOT NULL;` but that won't work in H2. If you want to maintain cross-dbms schema migrations you should look into Liquibase (and its XML format) rather then Flyway

Comment: Thanks. I've filed [H2 issue #694](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/694). If you would like to actually leave an answer here in Stack Overflow, I could mark it as correct (if there no better answers come in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct [syntax for Oracle 12.2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html#GUID-552E7373-BF93-477D-9DA3-B2C9386F2877__I2103956) is as you stated in the query:

```
ALTER TABLE foo MODIFY (bar VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL);
```

The statement will however execute correctly against Oracle without the outer parenthesises, which also works with H2 which will allow you to carry on. I found your [github issue #694](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/694) for which I'm adding a [pull request #703](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/pull/703) with a fix.

Comment: This is the model of a great answer! You gave me the correct syntax, with an authoritative reference. You provided a workaround. You filed a pull request for H2 to make things work better in the future. You didn't argue with me about whether I really wanted to do what I wanted to do. You were short and to the point, giving links as appropriate. What more could I ask for? Thank you very much!! I'm going to add a bounty to this question just so I can award it to you. Happy holidays!

Comment: Thanks for the kind feedback!

Comment: I can't resist circling back and giving one more thanks of appreciation. H2 1.4.197 was finally released, which contained your fix in https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/694 , and now our migration scripts work both with H2 and Oracle for this important feature. We are now using it in an upcoming release. You really helped out.

Answer (score 2):

I don't *speak* H2, but in *pure* Oracle it goes like

```
SQL> create table foo (bar varchar2(255));

Table created.

SQL> alter table foo modify bar not null;

Table altered.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try leaving out the parentheses:

```
ALTER TABLE foo MODIFY bar VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL;
```

Comment: But doesn't the Oracle production diagram at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm#SQLRF01001 indicate that parentheses are required?